# Issues with picamera

Tags: picamera

Hi I am having issues with my picamera, I have installed everything and enabled the camera but when I run the code and try to open the picture taken it says that it contains no data, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: Agree, and that should include *full* error messages. Add this information to your question.

Comment: What results do you get from a `vcgencmd get_camera` command. Paste the results from that into your question.

Comment: Your question is to vague. Nobody can answer it. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.